Violation of the Law of Total Expectation in the Unit Square?

I am wondering if anyone could help me make sense of the following observation: Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, independently and identically distributed on $U[0,1]$. We can depict different realizations of $(X,Y)$ in the unit square, and the joint density of $(X,Y)$, defined on the square, equals $1$.
Now, fix $x \in [0.5, 1]$ arbitrarily. Let $L(x)\subset[0,1]^2$ denote the set of the points represented by the lines connecting $(0,2x-1)$, $(x, 2x-1)$, and $(x,0)$. Please see the thick red lines in the figure. For any $x\in (0.5, 1]$, the set $L(x)$ is reverse L-shaped, where the kink is located on the line connecting $(0.5, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$. Set $L(0.5)$ is the line connecting $(0.0)$ and $(0.5, 0)$.
My question is the following: The unconditional expectation of $X-Y$ is equal to $0$, because $X$ and $Y$ have the same mean, $0.5$. However, we seem to have $\mathbb{E}[X-Y| (X,Y) \in L(x)]>0$ for any $x \in [0.5, 1)$, and $\mathbb{E}[X-Y| (X,Y) \in L(1)]=0$. We also have $\cup_{x \in [0.5, 1]} L(x) = [0,1]^2$, i.e., the collection of sets $\{L(x)\}_{x \in [0.5, 1]}$ is a partition of the unit square. Intuitively, as we vary $x$ from $0.5$ to $1$, we can cover the entire unit square, and each point belongs to exactly one "reversed L".
Some parts of my argument above must be incorrect, because I am claiming that even though $X-Y$ has mean $0$, we can partition the realizations of $(X,Y)$ so that conditional on each element of the partition, $X-Y$ has a strictly positive expectation. However, I am not able to figure out which part of the above logic is false. I'd appreciate if anyone could point out which part is wrong here. Thank you!
P.S. Let me elaborate on how I calculate $\mathbb{E}[X-Y|(X,Y) \in L(x)]$.
Conditional on $L(x)$, the probability of the horizontal line (connecting $(0,2x-1, x, 2x-1))$, which I denote by $A$, is
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{x + 2x-1} = \frac{x}{3x-1},
\end{equation}
where the denominator is the length of the "reversed L" and the numerator is the length of the line $A$. This may be the part I made a mistake, but I justified this calculation based on the fact that the joint density of $(X,Y)$ is uniform on $[0,1]^2$.
Now, conditional on $A$, we have
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[X-Y|(X,Y) \in A] = \mathbb{E}[X|(X,Y) \in A] -  \mathbb{E}[Y|(X,Y) \in A]= \frac{x}{2} - (2x-1).
\end{equation}
Repeating similar calculations for the vertical axis, we obtain
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X-Y|(X,Y) \in L(x)]
&= \frac{x}{3x-1}\left(\frac{x}{2} - (2x-1)\right) + \frac{2x-1}{3x-1} \left(x - \frac{2x-1}{2}\right)\\
&= \frac{x^2}{2(3x-1)} - \frac{(2x-1)^2}{2(3x-1)}\\
&= \frac{(1-x)(3x-1)}{2(3x-1)}\\
& = \frac{1}{2}(1-x),
\end{align}
which is always positive for $x<1$.

$L$ is a set of probability $0$, and when you are conditioning on a zero-probability event, you need to be extra-careful.

I agree with you. I have added my calculation of $\mathbb{E}[X-Y|(X,Y) \in L(x)]$ at the bottom of my question, which may clarify which part I got wrong. Thanks.

Expanding a little on Dilip's comment: $\mathbb{E}[X \mid (X, Y) \in A]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y \mid (X, Y) \in A]$ are undefined because $\mathbb{P}[(X, Y) \in A] = 0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Conditioning_on_an_event_of_probability_zero and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_paradox

Then show that $T(x)$ is $E[X - Y | K]$, where $x$ corresponds to the center of the respective segment.
Nice paradox. But consider

as we vary $x$  from $0.5$  to $1$, we can cover the entire unit square, and each point belongs to exactly one "reversed L".

To attain that, those infinitesimal reversed L's should have different widths: the horizontal lengths would be twice as thick as the vertical ones.
Namely, let $V(x), H(x)$ be the contribution of the vertical  and horizontal and leg resp. Then
$$V(x) = \int_0^{2x-1} (x-t) \, dt = x - \frac12$$
$$H(x) = \int_0^x t - (2x-1) \, dt = x - \frac32 x^2$$
If you just sum them (as you implicitly did) then indeed $V(x) + H(x) \ge 0 $ in $\frac12 \le x \le 1$
But the right thing to do consider is $T(x) = V(x) + 2 H(x)= 3x(1-x) -\frac12$,
which corresponds to the true $E[X-Y|(X,Y) \in L(x)] \times P((X,Y) \in L(x))$, and which takes the two signs in the interval. Further
$$ \int_{1/2}^1 T(x) dx = 0$$
as expected.

Edit: more in detail. Let's divide the interval $[\frac12,1]$ in $n$ segments of length $\Delta = \frac{1}{2n}$, for some large $n$. Let number those segments $k\in \{ 1,2 \cdots n\}$, and for each one let $x=x(k)=\frac12 + \Delta(k-\frac12)$ be its midpoint. The segments also divides the square into $n$ regions ("reversed L"), of area $A = \Delta (2x-1)  + 2 \Delta \, x = \Delta (4x -1)$. Let $K=g(X,Y) \in \{ 1,2 \cdots n\}$ be the random variable that corresponds to the region where the point $(X,Y)$ belongs.
$$\begin{align}
E[X-Y|K=k] &= \frac{1}{A}\left( \int_0^\Delta \int_0^{2x-1} (x-t) \, dt \, du + \int_0^{2\Delta} \int_0^{x} t - (2x-1) \, dt \, du  \right)\\
&=\frac{\Delta}{A}\left( V(x) + 2 H(x) \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4x-1}\left( 3x(1-x) -\frac12\right)
\end{align}$$
This attains both signs in $[1/2,1]$. And
$$E[E[X-Y|K]] = \int_{1/2}^{1}  \left( 3x(1-x) -\frac12\right) dx = 0$$

+1: Taking limits is an approach to dealing with conditioning on events of probability $0$, and if there is more than one sensible way to do it then you risk results like the Borel–Kolmogorov paradox.  Here "cover the entire unit square" in the question could be a constraint leading to your "horizontal lengths would be twice as thick as the vertical ones".

I think there is a small error: $A=\Delta(4x-1)$.

@Speltzu Thanks. Fixed, I hope

Here, in this jumble of ideas, what is really being talked about is conditioning by $max(2X-1,Y)$, if we calculate it:
$$E[X-Y\mid max(2X-1,Y)=v]=\frac{1-3v^2}{4+8v}$$
we see that it takes positive and negative values contrary to what the OP says.
